# After updating VS Code, I lost all of my extensions and settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS code portable version.

I always download the 64bit .zip file. After downloading:

I delete all old version files except "bin" folder
I move the new version to the folder in which I kept "bin" folder.

This is the procedure I always do, but this time when I run the new version I don't see my installed extensions and settings!

Comment: where did you install the extensions to? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable#_enable-portable-mode

Comment: I always install extensions by going to Manage > Extensions and then search and install them

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was saying. Did you read what I linked you to?

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I thought we must have/kept "bin" folder for portable mode. What is the purpose of "bin" folder then? Do we still need to keep this folder in portable mode (when updating)?